# Can you reverse a bash script with a series of mv commands?

Tags: mv

If I have a script rename_everything.sh which contains

```
mv 2022-05-03.txt hike_valley.txt
mv 2022-05-20.txt not_overcooked.txt
mv 2022-05-22.txt return_trip.txt
```

but am nervous to run that in the one folder with

```
bash rename_everything.sh
```

If I decide to do that, and then think it was a bad idea and regret it, can that .sh file be called in such a way that it will do the complete reverse of what it just did?

Comment: No. You could take a backup before running the script though.

Comment: In fact, it's a good idea to always work on a backup copy of important data (or, alternatively, take a backup first)...it will always be easier to revert to the original data than trying to undo any changes you made to it.   You can use `cp`, `rsync`, `tar` and/or many other programs to make backup copies.  Also, `git` can be a useful tool to have a revision history for any kind of files, not just source code...and it works especially well with text files.  it's also "smart" enough to recognise when a file has been renamed and record that rename operation in the history.

Comment: I use filesystems with CoW and snapshots (usually Btrfs) and often `cp --reflink=always` important data before I mess with it.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski what does that `cp --reflink=always` do and what is CoW?

Comment: @cardamom It's about creating a "copy" that initially takes little to none additional disk space, (almost like hardlinks), but (unlike hardlinks) reflinked files can be modified independently. [CoW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general there is no command that undoes `mv 2022-05-03.txt hike_valley.txt`.

At first glance `mv hike_valley.txt 2022-05-03.txt` seems to be such "undo" command. But imagine a regular file `hike_valley.txt` had existed and was *overwritten* by the first command. The original content of it is not easily recoverable. For sure the alleged "undo" command does not recover the original content.

Another case is if `hike_valley.txt` is a directory (it may be) or a symlink to a directory. In such case the first command creates or overwrites `hike_valley.txt/2022-05-03.txt`. Here an alleged "undo" is `mv hike_valley.txt/2022-05-03.txt ./` which is already different than the "undo" from above. And again it does not really undo, if overwriting happened.

The same reasoning applies to each `mv` command in your script.

Comment: ... so implementing a general backup strategy for the system (or at least making copies of essential data) is advisable before testing random commands that one does not know what they do.

Comment: @Kusalananda Better yet, never run "commands that one does not know what they do"

Comment: @RobertSmith Learning is quicker if one embraces mistakes.

Comment: @Kusalananda There are exponentially many more ways to make a mistake from which you learn nothing, so be careful with that line of reasoning.

Comment: @RobertSmith With `mv`? It is extremely illustrative to try moving files and directories around while learning to use the command line. It's is _useful_ to make mistakes while doing so. One sees with one's own eyes what happens and can hopefully figure out why (possibly with some help from people like us). Through testing, failing, and examining comes a lot of learning.  If you try to lean as for an exam, where failure is not an option, then you don't gain much understading of how the pieces fit together.

Comment: @RobertSmith (Connecting with my initial comment) Learning to make backups, and to restore from backup when it's needed, is good, don't you agree?

Comment: @Kusalananda Well, your previous comment on learning was very general, so I answered in kind. Yes, it is useful to make mistakes and learning from them. It is even more useful to learn how to get things right, which usually happens after making several mistakes. Learning how to make backups is undeniably a good thing.